# Google Forms Html

Tags: html, css

I made a google forum and I copied it's HTML code to put it on my own website. The code works when there is no background image on the page, but when I put a background image it is gone. I tried putting it above the image with index and more but it never seemed to work. Any solutions?

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(20, 26, 35,0.55),rgba(20, 26, 35, 0.55)),
                url("../img/minecraft.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSekkPJOyDhurz628H4ITig0AJcAx4dzU5e9xRlknsq1eFqSMA/viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="1757" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
<div class="applycontainer">
    <div class="applylogo">
        <!-- In the img folder, upload your logo -->
        <!-- Make sure you name it 'logo.png' -->
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="PvP Hut Logo">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Amessihel — That doesn't matter. The start and end tags are both (independently) optional on the body element.

Comment: @Amessihel — It's valid. The behaviour is the same in or out of quirks mode.

Comment: HTML was designed to be concise to write. It's only when XML came along that people become obsessed with being explicit about every tag.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/hulutiguzi/1/edit?html,css,output — I can't reproduce the problem